# Magento 1.7 add Pagination in product viewed not working

Tags: magento, pagination, magento-1.7

Product viewed located here:

```
App/code/local/Mage/Reports/Block/Product/Viewed.php
```

I have added the following code:

```
class Mage_Reports_Block_Product_Viewed extends Mage_Reports_Block_Product_Abstract{
    ...
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();

        $toolbar = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list_toolbar', microtime())
            ->setCollection($this->getProductCollection());

        $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager', microtime());
        $toolbar->setChild('product_list_toolbar_pager', $pager);

        $this->setChild('toolbar', $toolbar);
        $this->getProductCollection()->load();

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPagerHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('toolbar');
    }
}
```

My template should be like this:

```
<?php if ($_products = $this->getRecentlyViewedProducts()): ?>
<!-- top pagination -->
<?php echo $this->getPagerHtml(); ?>
<?php if($_collection->getSize()): ?>   
 ...
<?php foreach ($_collection as $_item): ?>      
　　 ...
　　<?php endforeach; ?>
　　
<?php endif ?>
<!-- bottom pagination -->
<?php echo $this->getPagerHtml(); ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

I'm added code not working in `Viewed.php`. Can someone please help me solve this problem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your Block code under : `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Viewed.php`
And make the class name changes respectively .
If your code is correct , it should work .

Comment: how to add pagination in this class `Mage_Reports_Block_Product_Viewed`?